# Unable to display WEBAPI data in Angularjs repeat directive

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

Can somebody help in displaying webapi data in angularjs repeat directive in my first Angular application?

I'm getting data from the WEBAPI as expected like below

```
[{"FLAVOR_ID":"BES","FLAVOR_NAME":"BES"},{"FLAVOR_ID":"BUN","FLAVOR_NAME":"BUN"}]
```

API Controller:

```
public class ItemMaintenanceController : ApiController
    {
        ItemMaintenanceRepository itemRepository;
        public ItemMaintenanceController(ItemMaintenanceRepository _itemRepository)
        {
            itemRepository = _itemRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<MA_Flavor> GetAllFlavors()
        {
               return itemRepository.GetAllFlavors();
        }     
    }
```

Client.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Client</title>    
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script>
        alert("start");
        var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngResource']);

        var controller = function ($scope, $resource) {  // controller uses $resource, which is part of ngResource
            $scope.flavor = {};
            $scope.getFlavors = function () {
                alert("calling getflvors");
                var request = $resource("http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors?Id=CMN");
                $scope.flavor = request.query();
            };

            ////$scope.clear = function () {
            ////    $scope.flavor = {};
            ////    $scope.error = "";
            ////}

            $scope.getFlavors();
            myapp.controller("ItemMaintenanceController", controller);

  </script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="contacts">
    <div ng-controller="ItemMaintenanceController">    

    <select ng-model="flavor">
        <option ng-repeat="fl in Flavor" value="{{fl.FLAVOR_NAME}}">{{fl.FLAVOR_NAME}}</option>
    </select>

    <h1>You selected: {{flavor.FLAVOR_NAME}}</h1>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: angular.module is myapp, ng-app is contacts, to troubleshoot I recommend set aside what's the real issue first, use hardcoded data first and let your angular app works first before getting data in your api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue with the names of the ng-controller, ng-module and ng-app. Try to change and hope it will work.

```
<body ng-app="contacts">
    <div ng-controller="ItemMaintenanceController"> 

<Script>
 var app = angular.module('contacts', []);

        // To fetch all falvors 
        app.controller("ItemMaintenanceController", function ($scope, $http) {

.....
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. based on what you have I think something like this should work:

```
<select ng-model="selectedFlavorId">
    <option ng-repeat="fl in flavor" value="{{fl.FLAVOR_ID}}">{{fl.FLAVOR_NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

your data is in `$scope.flavor` and I assume that if you debug it will look like this:

```
$scope.flavor = [{"FLAVOR_ID":"BES","FLAVOR_NAME":"BES"},{"FLAVOR_ID":"BUN","FLAVOR_NAME":"BUN"}]
```

you want the id in your value field as that is the bit you need to know which value you selected. the value you see in dropdown should be the name of the flavor.

when you select something, that value will be reflected in the model.

as I chose *selectedFlavorId*, you will find that populated under `$scope.selectedFlavorId`. Do not override your API data with the selected value like you've just done.

*selectedFlavorId* will give you the ID of the item you selected so you need a bit more code after this to get the name of that property from your data array.

Comment: Thxs for your reply. It was not going inside the script to display first alert itself. Not sure where is the issue...

Comment: in that case I'd go back to angular website, learn how to get a basic app working first, then worry about APIs and how to display data.

Answer (score 0):

There may following issues in your code.

1. Your angular modules defined as `myapp` and in `ng-app` you have used
   `contacts`.
2. You have to create two different scope variables, one for the `flavor`
   and another is `flavors`. `flavors` you need to use under the `ng-options`
   and flavor you have to use for `ng-model`.
3. What I understood `request.query()` will return the resource object,
   So have two options to get data from the query. More details about
   the resource you can find [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

   ```
   var request = $resource("http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors?Id=CMN");
   ```

   **Option 1**

   ```
   request.query(function(data) {
       $scope.flavor = data;
   });
   ```

   **Option 2**

   ```
   request.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
      // success
      $scope.flavor = data;
   }, function(errResponse) {
      // fail
   });
   ```